# Updating chat client singnalR in swift

Tags: ios, swift, signalr, swiftr

I am using [SwiftR](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR) to integrate signalR chat client in swift. I Converted my obj-c code to swift step by step. Nothing i'm getting from callaback methods as response. Its not even hitting the break point inside the callback

```
           SwiftR.connect("https://chat.f.com") { connection in
        connection.headers=["Authorization":bearerKey]

        self.chatHub = connection.createHubProxy("MobileChatHub")

        self.chatHub?.on("ChatContactsResponse", callback: { (response) in
            print("ChatContactsResponse")
            print(response as AnyObject)
        })
        self.chatHub?.on("GetChatsResponse", callback: { (response) in
            print("GetChatsResponse")
            print(response as AnyObject)
        })
        self.chatHub?.on("GetChatsResponse", callback: { (response) in
            print("GetChatsResponse")
            print(response as AnyObject)
        })

        connection.starting = { print("started")}
        connection.connected = { print("connected: \(connection.connectionID)") }
        connection.connectionSlow = { print("connectionSlow") }
        connection.reconnecting = { print("reconnecting") }
        connection.reconnected = { print("reconnected") }
        connection.disconnected = { print("disconnected")}
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Swift/Objective-C clients but in general SignalR server requires to know hubs when the connection is being started. If I read this code correctly you first start the connection and then create a hub proxy. Have you tried creating the proxy first and then starting the connection? This way the client would know about the hubs you won't to use and will send it to the server as connectionData when starting the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing right.

But you've forgot `connection.start()`
If you're looking into [this](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/blob/master/SwiftR%20iOS%20Demo/DemoViewController.swift) demo then find [#127 line here](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/blob/master/SwiftR%20iOS%20Demo/DemoViewController.swift#L127).